# Как вывести сообщение из дискорда в python в командную строку (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

Хотел сделать бота для общения Админа через командную строку бота.
Можно ли как-то сделать чтобы сообщения из дискорда передавались в cmd. Также хотелось сделать функцию общения через эту командную строку с участниками дискорд сервера.
Вот измученный, нерабочий код.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 'Тут мой токен'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def test(ctx, arg):
while True:
    print(arg)
    text = input("Введите текст:")
    await ctx.send(text)


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: В cmd это ```print()```

Comment: Наверное бота надо в 2 потока запускать, чтоб в одном он отлавливал сообщения пользователей, в другом сообщения админа

Comment: @Nobody А как сделать чтобы он отправлял сообщение которое ты пишешь в консоли? У меня не выходит. (если нужно покажу код)

Comment: Ну как минимум надо знать айди канала, на который надо отправлять сообщение. Понятное дело что без просмотра вашего кода, вам на ошибки не укажут

Comment: @Nobody
```python
import discord    
from discord.ext import commands   

TOKEN = '123'   
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')   

@bot.command(pass_context=True)  # разрешаем передавать агрументы   
async def test(ctx, arg): # создаем асинхронную фунцию бота   
    print(ctx + ":" + arg)  # отправляем обратно аргумент   

bot.run(TOKEN)   
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    print('Message from {0.author}: {0.content}'.format(message))
```

Comment: Спасибо! А как сделать отправку сообщений из командной строки в дискорд? И можно ли это всё сделать в одном коде с получением в командную строку?